# Manipulate Bootstrap navbar elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do is to hide `<li>` elements from navbar to a dropdown menu on resize.

[image]

I tried and I've ended with this buggy menu. [http://i.imgur.com/1uJ7hbG.gif](https://i.imgur.com/1uJ7hbG.gif)

Here is the js:

```
$().ready(function () {
    //we reconstruct menu on window.resize
    $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
        var parentWidth = $("#normal").parent().width() - 40;
        var ulWidth = $(".menutohide").outerWidth();
        var menuLi = $("#normal > li");
        var liForMoving = new Array();
        //take all elements that can't fit parent width to array
        menuLi.each(function () {
            ulWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
            if (ulWidth > parentWidth) {
                console.log(ulWidth);
                liForMoving.push($(this));
            }
        });
        if (liForMoving.length > 0) {   //if have any in array -> move em to "more" ul
            e.preventDefault();
            liForMoving.forEach(function (item) {
                item.clone().appendTo(".links-hidden");
                item.remove();
            });
        }
        else if (ulWidth < parentWidth) { //check if we can put some 'li' back to menu
            liForMoving = new Array();
            var moved = $(".links-hidden > li");
            for (var i = moved.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //reverse order
                var tmpLi = $(moved[i]).clone();
                tmpLi.appendTo($("#normal"));
                ulWidth += $(moved[i]).outerWidth();
                if (ulWidth < parentWidth) {
                    $(moved[i]).remove();
                }
                else {
                    ulWidth -= $(moved[i]).outerWidth();
                    tmpLi.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        if ($(".links-hidden > li").length > 0) { //if we have elements in extended menu - show it
            $(".menutohide").show();
        }
        else {
            $(".menutohide").hide();
        }
    });

    $(window).trigger("resize"); //call resize handler to build menu right
});
```

And here is the html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="normal">
        <li><a href="#" class="first-child">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitch Live</a></li>
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Ranking</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav menutohide">
        <li class="dropdown hidden-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-fw"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu links-hidden" role="menu">
            <!--Hidden links here-->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                <h6 class="hidden-xs">Bambini</h6>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/000000"/>
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Account info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logoff</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use javascript on this instead of proper media queries in css?

Comment: @connexo : With media queries I can't achieve the effect I want, also I will have to write the `<li>` elements again.

Comment: People will probably not be able to help unless you provide a working fiddle. I'm not even sure what you want to achieve, though I'm almost certain you are highly overcomplicating stuff.

Comment: Can you share ur code please by creating fiddle.. It will be helpful for us to debug the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with a CSS `@media` query.  Just give whatever you want to hide some sort of id, and then you can use `display: none` to hide it.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #contact-nav-link {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d4L7ty4/) - the `<li>` element that says 'Contact' will display in the navbar, but when the window is resized (and the navbar collapses), it disappears from the dropdown list.